# Is there a way to run a db2 command without logging into the console?

Tags: database, db2

I know that for mysql if I run:

```
mysql (db name) -e "select x from table;"
```

from the linux command line i can retrieve the result.  So I don't have to connect to the db

I'm trying to find a way to do it for db2.  Everything I find indicates I'd need to do it from a bash script, which I don't want to do because I'd have to deploy that script to 700+ servers.

Is there a method that's like the mysql function that allows for this for db2?

Comment: To run a query in Db2, a connection to a database is a prerequisite. But depending on the exact configuration, and whether one is running remote or local , one can connect to a default database, with or without an explicit userid/password. So much depends on the precise configuration and the precise reqirement. Suggest you improve the precision of your question.

Comment: You certainly need to connect to a database (server) to access the data with all the database logic. Whether you connect explicitly or it is done in the background for you, is another question. What is your environment? Where is the Db2 database?

Comment: I believe I'm all set here.  As you've stated, I'll need to connect to the db before i can execute commands.  So instead of running my request in a single line, I've incorporated the request into a script.  Not the end of the world